# Why does this identity with the product $\prod_{p\mid n}(p+k)$ and recursive sum of divisors function is true?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum, divisor-counting-function

Let us define the following recursive function involving the sum of divisors function $\sigma(n)$:

\begin{array}{ l }
 r(n,1)=\sigma(n) \\ 
 r(n,2)=\sum_{d|n}r(d,1) \\  
 r(n,3)=\sum_{d|n}r(d,2) \\
 \ldots \\
 r(n,k)=\sum_{d|n}r(d,k-1) \\
\end{array}

If n is squarefree, then the following identiy seems to hold ($p$ are the prime factors of $n$ smaller than $n$):

$$r(n,k)=\prod_{p\mid n}(p+k)$$

An implementation in Mathematica verifies this empirically:

```
rn = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {k, _Integer}}, 
   Total[Nest[Catenate@*Divisors, {n}, k]]];
p[n_, k_] := Product[p + k, {p, Complement[Divisors[n], {1, n}]}];
Print[rn[10, 5]];
Print[p[10, 5]];
(* Output: 70 *)
```

***My question:***
Does there exist a theorem for this identity or (if not) how can we proof this identity?

Comment: Prove that $n\mapsto r(n,k)$ is multiplicative, and then that $r(p,k)=p+k$ using induction. It follows that $r(n,k)=\prod_{p\mid n}(p+k)$ for all square-free $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$n\mapsto r(n,k)$ is the Dirichlet convolution of $k$ copies of $\sigma$, which means it is multiplicative. Therefore, for all $n$ square-free,
$$
r(n,k) = \prod_{p\mid n}r(p,k).
$$
Now, we see that for all $k\ge 2$, we have $r(1,k)=\sum_{d\mid 1}r(1,k-1)=r(1,k-1)$ and it follows that $r(1,k)=1$. Next, for all $p$ prime and all $k\ge 2$
$$
r(p,k) = \sum_{d\mid p}r(d,k-1) = r(p,k-1) + r(1,k-1) = r(p,k-1) + 1,
$$
from which we conclude that $r(p,k)=r(p,1)+k-1=p+k$. Thus, for all square-free $n$,
$$
r(n,k) = \prod_{p\mid n}(p+k).
$$

Comment: There's a typo. It should be $$\sum_{d\mid p}r(d,k-1) = r(p,k-1) + r(1,k-1)$$

Comment: It's " ... the convolution of $k$ copies...”. The name of the operation is "convolution” (or "Dirichlet convolution" if you want to be more specific), not "convolution product"